# Indirect addressing on an assembly program with RAM locations

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, assembly

Here, I have written a indirect addressing assembly program (with PIC18) to
copy following to RAM locations ***10H to 16H.***
(It says MERHABA in turkish (means hello)

But, I am not sure that the part of my code **"LFSR 0,0x10"** was right or wrong...

For instance, if I would make it from ***12H to 14H*** to say Hey, then should I supposed to write
"**LFSR 0,0x0C"** like that?

It doesn't need to say hello or something. I just want to figure out that. If you could help me how to test it on mplab, that would be gorgeous
Thank you...

```
MOVLW 'M'
LFSR 0,0X10
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'E'
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'R'
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'H'
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'A'
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'B'
MOVWF INDF0
INCF FSR0L,F
MOVLW 'A'
MOVWF INDF0
```

Comment: Which micro-controller's ISA is this ...?

Comment: Looks like PIC assembly. Please add which PIC is in question. Have you read PIC assembly instruction manual to find out if it answers your question? Are you absolutely sure you wrote that, since otherwise you would already know how to change it? Is ths a school assignment to understand and modify a program?

Comment: @MituRaj I use PIC18 for my microcontroller lecture

Comment: @Justme Sorry, I forgot to add it. Let me correct my question please.

Comment: @Justme actually, 10H to 16H type was an example which my teacher showed us. After that, I wanted to learn to play on it. It can be from 11H to 12H and saying even "HI". So, my point is, I want to test my code whether it is working or not. Could you help me at that point? I'm preparing for my midterm.

Comment: @Justme I modified to understand and modify a program.

Comment: To address 12H and following, the initial instruction will be `LFSR 0,0X12`, not `LFSR 0,0X0C`. ;-) If you say that you use MPLab, why don't you just try? It does include a simulator, doesn't it? -- Anyway, at a first glance, it looks correct.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I will try it on mplab x ide today.

Comment: @thebusybee May I ask, why did you consider it 0X12? Shouldn't we write it with a HEX form which is 0C ?

Comment: Sure, but 12H is also hex, by the "H". I thought you knew, because you wrote 10H -> 0x10.